# Is Bootsrap5 compatible with React 18?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

Is Bootstrap 5 compatible with React?

I've read that prior versions of Bootstrap (before version 5) effect the DOM, and therefore are not compatible with React.  However, I heard that Bootstrap 5 is pure CSS.  Does this mean that it is compatible with React?

Edit:
I stand corrected.  It does use vanilla JS, but jQuery is removed.

I'm reading
https://superdevresources.com/bootstrap5-vs-bootstrap4-whats-new/

> 1. Vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery Ever since Bootstrap was introduced, it utilized jQuery as a dependency to offer dynamic
>    features such as menu expansion, carousel, dropdowns etc. However,
>    this forced dependency on jQuery was not liked by many developers who
>    wanted to use Bootstrap with modern JavaScript frameworks such as
>    React and Vue.js. With Bootstrap 5, they have removed this dependency.

It KIND of sounds like they remove jQuery, and that it allows compatibility with React and Vue.js.  But it doesn't actually says it's compatible.

Comment: Bootstrap 5 has some JS functionalities in it, and still depends on Popper.js. So it's not purely CSS. However, that shouldn't be related to React at all.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should really be asking the bootstrap folks, so they can add that to the docs (somewhere) so that everyone (including you) can now just find that information in the official docs.

Comment: See [Usage with javascript framework](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#usage-with-javascript-frameworks)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have try to use some component library from bootstrap. some updated library compatible with Bootstrap v5
i.e. `reactstrap` using Bootstrap `v5.1.0`